# Displaying dynamic data in JQplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Hello Guys I am using JQPlot to display a piechart. I am new to Jquery that is why is kind hard for me to manipulate arrays in Jquery.

This is the structure of  arrays that will pass to Jquery and it is dynamic

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Baseball' => string '12.18' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Basketball' => string '8.12' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Boxing' => string '5.54' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Golf' => string '6.64' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Soccer' => string '36.90' (length=5)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Tennis' => string '27.31' (length=5)
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Football' => string '2.21' (length=4)
  7 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Hockey' => string '1.11' (length=4)
```

And I want this data to display on my pie chart. So far this is my code.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        var sports = $('#sports').val();
        // sports - this variable holds the data array 
        jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1',[sports], 
        [[['Verwerkende FruedenStunde Companaziert Eine industrie', 9],['Retail', 8], ['Primaire producent', 7], 
        ['Out of home', 6],['Groothandel', 5], ['Grondstof', 4], ['Consument', 3], ['Bewerkende industrie', 2]]], `
// this is where i put the data from array but idont know  how` 
        {
            title: '', 
            seriesDefaults: {
            shadow: false, 
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
            rendererOptions: { padding: 2, sliceMargin: 2, showDataLabels: true } 
             }, 
        legend: { show:true, location: 'w' }
        });
    });
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: How can i put my data  in plot1?

Comment: I want to display the array above and assign it in plot1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s = $.parseJSON($('#sports').val());
    var s1= [];
    for(d in s)
    {
        for (ix in s[d]) {
            s1.push([ix , parseFloat(s[d][ix])])
        }
    }
    console.log(s1)

    jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1',[s1],
    {
        title: 'Percentage of Bets by Sport', 
        seriesDefaults: {
        shadow: false, 
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
        rendererOptions: { 
            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabelThreshold:0,
            padding: 20, 
            sliceMargin: 2, 
            diameter: 400,
            showDataLabels: true } 
         }, 
    legend: { show:true, location: 'ne' }
    });
});
```